# pd.Series string replacement modifying values unexpectedly

Tags: python, pandas

I assume there is something I am missing with my understanding of string replacement. Your help is appreciated in advance.

I have a data frame similar to below:

```
combine_cols = pd.DataFrame({'totalannualmembers' : [85494.0, np.NaN, np.NaN], 
              'totalannualmembershipssold' : [np.NaN, 90000.0, np.NaN]})
```

I want to merge or combine the 2 columns into a single columns. To do so, I replace NaN with empty strings and convert the columns to str type. The code below combines the 2 columns.

```
join_cols = ['totalannualmembers', 'totalannualmembershipssold']

#fill NaN with empty string
combine_cols.fillna('', axis = 1, inplace = True)

#convert columns to str type
combine_cols = combine_cols[join_cols].astype(str)

#combine into a single column
combine_cols['combine_test'] = combine_cols['totalannualmembers'].str.cat(combine_cols['totalannualmembershipssold'],sep="")
```

My problem arises when I try to convert the `combine_cols.combine_test` column back to an integer / float type due to empty strings. I have tried replacing empty strings with the following:

```
combine_cols.combine_test = combine_cols.combine_test.str.replace('', '9999')
```

While this changes the empty strings, it also seems to be changing the values I want to keep. For example, combine_test index 550 also changes when the desired output is to remain as 85494.0.

```
combine_cols.iloc[550]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
totalannualmembers                                            85494.0
totalannualmembershipssold                                           
combine_test                  99998999959999499999999949999.999909999
Name: 550, dtype: object
```

Is there a better way to merge these 2 columns into one or to convert the empty strings so I can convert the column back to a float type for analysis?

The desired output for combine_cols.combine_test would be:

```
0       85494.0
1       90000.0
2       NaN
```

Comment: What happens if there are two existing values ? Meaning neither column have `np.nan`.

Comment: That instance did not appear in my data. The resulting data frame was a merged data frame from several csv files and both columns were never used simultaneously

Comment: You may want to look at the other answers. Additionnally, you might want to consider using [combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html) if you wish to merge multiple columns together from different dataframes (Assuming you used `pd.read_csv`)

Comment: I was just examining yours and David's solutions and greatly appreciate the greater efficiency and simple alternatives. I appreciate the information for me to improve -- thanks to you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with `fillna`:

```
combine_cols['combine_test'] = (combine_cols['totalannualmembers']
                                   .fillna(combine_cols.totalannualmembershipssold)
                               )
```

Output:

```
   totalannualmembers  totalannualmembershipssold  combine_test
0             85494.0                         NaN       85494.0
1                 NaN                     90000.0       90000.0
2                 NaN                         NaN           NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the approach that you must follow is:

```
combine_cols.combine_test[combine_cols.combine_test == ""] = "9999"
```

with `combine_cols.combine_test[combine_cols.combine_test == ""]` we are asking to our data frame to search only the rows on the **combine_test** column that matches an empty string and we are replacing it with the string **"9999"**.

Please let me know if this helps :D!

Comment: great simple solution can't believe I didn't consider index assignment; thanks

Comment: you are very welcome :D, good luck with your project! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

A more "fun" way to do it :) if you are looking for a one-liner after creating the dataframe.

```
combine_cols.melt(value_name='combine_test').drop('variable', axis=1).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

1) Melt the columns into one combined column with the column headers being moved to rows and name the column 'combine_test'

2) Drop the unnecessary 'variable' column that was created where the column headers became rows from melting.

3) Drop the duplicate rows and reset the index to 0, 1, 2 and pass drop=True to avoid adding new column after reset.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems too complicated for what you wish to do to me.
You may simply want to do...

Plus, as you don't deal with strings... it must be faster.

```py
combine_cols = pd.DataFrame({
    'totalannualmembers' : [85494.0, np.NaN, np.NaN], 
    'totalannualmembershipssold' : [np.NaN, 90000.0, np.NaN]
})

combine_cols['test'] = combine_cols.loc[:, 'totalannualmembers']

mask = combine_cols['totalannualmembers'].isna()
combine_cols.loc[mask, 'test'] = combine_cols.loc[mask, 'totalannualmembershipssold']
print(combine_cols)
# 0             85494.0                         NaN  85494.0
# 1                 NaN                     90000.0  90000.0
# 2                 NaN                         NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pandas.concat() and see if it works for you. I also removed all missing values using pandas.DataFrame.dropna() and reseted index using pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.

```
combine_cols = pd.concat([combine_cols['totalannualmembers'],combine_cols['totalannualmembershipssold']], ignore_index=True)
combine_cols.dropna(inplace=True)
combine_cols.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(combine_cols)
```

The output for this should be:

```
0    85494.0
1    90000.0
dtype: float64
```

Check this websites for more information about those :

[1] https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

[2] https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

[3] https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html